# Why would you treat a cat with a ball of ingested fur with Cola and xray contrast liquid?

Tags: cats, grooming, veterinarian, digestion

I am referring to [this (peer-reviewed) publication](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/37529386/) from Wilson et al. (2023) where the authors claimed to have used a mixture of 55 mL of Coca-Cola and 5 mL of iohexol for the treatment of a small intestinal trichobezoar.

Why these two liquids used? what is normally used for the "hydraulical" treatment of trichobezoar?

Are there home-ready alternatives (I mean, the iohexol is not as readily available as Coca-Cola)?

Wilson S, Dobbins D, Kawalilak L, Parambeth JC. *Endoscopic administration of Coca-Cola for medical management of a wedged intestinal trichobezoar in a cat*. Can Vet J. 2023 Aug;64(8):747-752. PMID: 37529386; PMCID: PMC10352036.

Comment: You'd have to read the paper, not the abstract, to learn why these materials were selected. Otherwise we're just guessing. I can see possible reasons. On the other hand I'd be willing to believe this a joke or hoax.

Comment: I'd guess the contrast liquid is to see the effects.

Comment: @keshlam I am not a practitioner of the field. Reading the paper is unlikely to bring me to understand whether it is a joke or a hoax. On the other hand, someone familiar with the topic *will* surely understand whether it is a joke or a hoax. And they may have access to the full paper, which I don't.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many papers contain crazy procedures and absurd ideas. Have a look at the [ig-nobel price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ig_Nobel_Prize) for a selection of papers. Many of them look like hoaxes at first glance, but in today's scientific community, which clings to ceremonies and procedures while forcing people to publish paper after paper, you sometimes have to leave the beaten path in order to make progress. How many chemicals were "developed" by forgetting experiments in the fridge? How many sweeteners by chemists licking their dirty hands? This is how science works

Comment: @Elmy oh yes, sure, even the foundations of modern world logistics (tires) came out of years of relentless efforts from Charles Goodyear (ignoring the anedoctal discovery of vulcanization, I cannot vouche whether it is true or not, it is true that he was derided all along his life for trying to get something useful out of rubber...). Fast forward 150 years, I hope that scientists or at least people that have the interest in reading scientific papers have a more open-minded view.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thanks for pointing the obvious (that I completely missed!)

Comment: In addition - if you're willing to wait https://europepmc.org/article/med/37529386 seems to suggest the article will be out free in november

Answer (score 4):

Please note that this is mostly speculation since I don't have access to the full article.

**Case summary in common English**

A hairball (*medical term: Trichobezoar; [link to image](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezoar#/media/Datei:Long-haired-cat-hairball.jpg) with a warning for disgusting content*) was blocking the small intestine of a cat. The vets inserted an endoscope to diagnose the cat (*from the abstract of the paper it's not clear whether they inserted the endoscope through a natural orifice or an incision*) and they could see the hairball, but couldn't reach it with their instruments to remove it. So they flushed the intestine with 55 ml Coca Cola and 5 ml iohexol (x-ray contrast agent). The hairball passed naturally without further problems.

**Why Coca Cola?**

Probably because that was what the vets had on hand. Cutting the lower stomach and intestines to remove an object is a major surgical intervention with a lot of risks involved and a long recovery time. If you are *so close* to solving the problem without having to do that, you try anything reasonable you have at hand.

Cola cannot dissolve hairs, so it certainly didn't make the hairball vanish. However, the acids in Cola can dissolve some other gunk that might have slowed the natural passing of the hairball down.

The introduction of any liquid also inflates the intestine. If the hairball (which is usually an elongated shape) was stuck before a bend in the intestine, this slight inflation could be enough to straighten this section enough to let the obstruction pass through.

Also, the additional liquid lubricates the intestinal wall and the hairball to help it pass naturally.

Maybe some air bubbles from the carbonation can also stick to uneven surfaces and smooth them out, but this is pure speculation. I don't know to which extend the vets removed the carbonation prior to injecting the Cola.

**Why iohexol**

Simply to be able to observe whether or not the obstruction clears out.

**What are the alternatives?**

Since I'm not a vet I cannot answer how similar cases are usually treated. The authors of the paper implied that they tried to grab the obstruction with surgical instruments like endoscopic tongs but couldn't reach it. I know that pulling objects and tissue through the endoscope is common practice and can involve cutting or otherwise fragmenting too large objects first.

I have no idea if a "hydraulic" approach is common or something these vets came up with.

**Personal opinion**

While I suspect that simple water or carbonated water could have been successful as well, I respect the authors  Wilson, Savanah; Dobbins, Devin; Kawalilak, Lukas; Parambeth, Joseph C. for trying out their unusual approach. Solving a possibly lethal intestinal obstruction without major surgical intervention is an accomplishment.

That being said, there's a possibility that the obstruction could have cleared on it's own and the vets admitted that more studies need to be done to determine the effectiveness of the procedure.

Comment: My one concern is that between the caramel coloring and the caffeine, cola seems an odd choice. Yes, the phosphoric acid therein might have been a reason. As a layman I'd hesitate to carbonate an incision (seems like begging for increased leakage) but if done via natural access my uneducated guess is that it's probably not more dangerous than the rest of the treatment. If it worked, it's worth writing up, I admit... and avoiding more drastic surgery, even if laparoscopic, would be worthwhile.

Comment: I think they did - and the amount needed is small.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer—I'm not a vet nor a medical practitioner, so my interpretation of this should be taken with a ... swig of Coca-Cola, or something stronger.

One of the abstracts for the paper [Endoscopic administration of Coca-Cola for medical management of a wedged intestinal trichobezoar in a cat.](https://europepmc.org/article/med/37529386), references [Successful Treatment with a Combination of Endoscopic Injection and Irrigation with Coca Cola for Gastric Bezoar-induced Gastric Outlet Obstruction](https://journals.lww.com/jcma/abstract/2008/01000/successful_treatment_with_a_combination_of.10.aspx) in the Journal of the Chinese Medical Association, which is available in its entirety on that page (see the PDF under the download link on the left sidebar)

As per the paper:

> Gastric bezoar formation occurs in patients with altered gastric physiology, impaired gastric emptying and/or reduced acid production.

and that

> "The efficacy of nasogastric lavage with Coca Cola for dissolution of gastric bezoars and direct intrabezoar infusion endoscopically has been reported in Greece, Japan and South Korea"

As for why

> The mechanism of Coca Cola dissolution is not well understood. Acid is important in digesting fiber. Coca Cola, which has a pH of 2.6, may be a substitute for normal gastric acidity.4,6 In addition, it has been suggested that the NaHCO3 contained in Coca Cola has a mucolytic effect.12 Furthermore, penetration of CO2 bubbles into the surface of bezoars may digest the fibers of concretion. The combined action of NaHCO3 and CO2 as well as unknown agents in Coca Cola are considered the important factors in dissolving bezoars.

This indicates they don't actually know but it works, but suspect Coke is similar to stomach acid and either dissolves or softens the besoar for removal and directly injecting it into a bezoar works fairly rapidly, which might be a concern for a senior cat.

In short, it works in humans *really* effectively and in this situation apparently proved effective in cats too when they tried it.

Comment: "see the PDF link"—Clarification please: neither of the links you added lead to a pdf.

Comment: The "another paper" link has a PDF on its left sidebar ...labelled download